# Bibtex warning No data sources defined! Overleaf without using bibliography commands

Tags: bibtex, overleaf, warnings

I made a project in Overleaf starting with this settings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{enumitem}   
\usepackage{comment}   
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,newverbs,xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\title{...}
\author{..}
\date{March 2021}
% Here I have some fancy mathematical definitions such as
%\def\dd{e^{-2\pi x\xi i}}
%\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
%
\marginsize{1.2cm}{1.5cm}{1cm}{1cm}
\begin{document}
```

Then I have text and equations and the final \end{document} option.
I haven't used any bibliography-like packages nor any references to citations. I also don't have any command using the word bibliography but I still get the warning:

```
BibTeX: No data sources defined!
```

I would like to get rid of this warning because I don't think its appeareance makes any sense at all. I think that maybe documentclass article has bibtex by default but I got the same when I changed to report. So I only want to disable this default option in my overleaf project if it's possible.

Comment: Please always post full minimal self contained examples that others can test as is. Then the code we are testing is the same as on your system. Additionally remember to make it minimal, i.e. remove packages that are irrelevant for the problem.

Comment: Unrelated drop `latexsym` (it uses an entire alphabet for just a handful of symbols you probably don't use). `amstext` is auto loaded by `amsmath` so no need to do it manually. Use `xcolor` instead of `color`.

Comment: And, don't load `colortbl` and `xcolor` independently of each other. Instead, run `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` to assure maximal compatibility between the packages.

Comment: Hello there! Tom from Overleaf Support Team here. I don't know what could cause this. But you can reach me on Overleaf support email address and we can see what's going on there. Then if it's something worth sharing with others, I will make an answer here.

Comment: @daleif, I left all the packages bc I considered that maybe one of them was the actual problem. I also don't understand why you advise me to share self contained examples, like I literally don't get the meaning of that. Can't anybody compile exactly the same I do with the code I posted using overleaf? Thanks for the recommendations but I don't get it.

Comment: If I am using too many packages it's because that was a shared project with a fellow mathematician student. But in this case I really appreciate the knowledge about useless or uncompatible packages you and @Mico are sharing

Comment: I solved the problem by elimminating the cache, more precisely the bbl file from the auxiliar files. I think this residual file was confusing overleaf because, in a previous version (that I had already compiled, modified and compiled again) I did have the \usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

Comment: The main point is that for people to help they need to be able to compile a similar example on their system that you are doing. You only posted a preamble, and so others have to guess an example body to test. We gave had many cases where users have withheld important information that could have been solved in an instant. This also an important debugging tool as preparing this self contained (that does not use and non supplied tex files, no non available images etc) will often lead the user to find the problem them self.

Comment: One such tool in the process is to make the example minimal, aka only load the packages needed to show the problem. In that process you may discover that your problem is related to two packages being incompatible. Lastly once the minimal example is made then also providing the log fir the compilation on your side is useful for debugging.